# Can't set custom font for pdf for PdfContentByte - DroidText/iText library

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I'm trying to use a custom font, I don't get any error but it doesn't take it into account.

```
Rectangle pageSize = basePdf.getPageSize(i);

PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = stamper.getOverContent(i);

// Use custom font
if (!FontFactory.isRegistered(FUTURA_LIGHT)) {
    FileHelper.copyFileFromAssetsToInternalStorage(mContext, FONT_PATH_IN_ASSETS);
    FontFactory.register(mContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + FONT_PATH_IN_ASSETS, FUTURA_LIGHT);
}
Font myFont = FontFactory.getFont(FUTURA_LIGHT);
BaseFont font = myFont.getBaseFont();

pdfContentByte.saveState();

pdfContentByte.stroke();
pdfContentByte.restoreState();
// Start to add text
pdfContentByte.beginText();
pdfContentByte.setFontAndSize(font, 6);
if (fontColor != null) {
    pdfContentByte.setColorFill(fontColor);
}

pdfContentByte.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, message, pageSize.getWidth() / 2, 40, 0);
pdfContentByte.endText();
```

I've checked and the font is indeed registered, it just doesn't apply it to the PDF.

Comment: What does *it doesn't take it into account* mean? Do you get the message in some other font? Or not at all? Please supply a sample result.

Comment: the message is printed but with the default font

Comment: i've tried multiple fonts, fetching the font file elsewhere(assets and internal storage) with the same result

Comment: Please supply a sample result PDF and also provide the version of the iText library you use.

Comment: I'm using droidText 0.5 which is based off iText 2.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by accident, I was trying to display accents by adding `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`

here's the line that I changed:

```
Font myFont = FontFactory.getFont(FUTURA_LIGHT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

because using **Thai font**.

My resolve to below,

```
String FONT_DEFAULT = ROOT_PATH + "/assets/THSarabunNew/THSarabunNew.ttf";

PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1);

pdfContentByte.beginText();
pdfContentByte.setFontAndSize(
        BaseFont.createFont(
                FONT_DEFAULT,
                BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
                BaseFont.EMBEDDED
        ), 12);
pdfContentByte.setTextMatrix(50, 760); // set x and y co-ordinates
pdfContentByte.showText("สวัสดีครับ"); // add the text
pdfContentByte.endText();
```

Work for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```